# Pandas dataframe take group max value per group when groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe with many columns, 2 are categorical and the rest are numeric:

```
df = [type1 , type2 , type3 , val1, val2, val3
       a       b        q       1    2     3
       a       c        w       3    5     2
       b       c        t       2    9     0
       a       b        p       4    6     7
       a       c        m       2    1     8]
```

I want to apply a merge based on the operation `groupby(["type1","type2"])` that will create take the max value from the grouped row:

```
df = [type1 , type2 ,type3, val1, val2, val3 
       a       b       q      2    6     7     
       a       c       w      4    5     8      
       b       c       t      2    9     0
```

Explanation: `val3` of first row is 7 because this is the maximal value when `type1 = a, type2 = b`.

Similarly, `val3` of second row is 8 because this is the maximal value when `type1 = a, type2 = c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need aggregate all columns by `max`:

```
df = df.groupby(["type1","type2"]).max()
print (df)
            type3  val1  val2  val3
type1 type2                        
a     b         q     4     6     7
      c         w     3     5     8
b     c         t     2     9     0
```

If need some columns aggregate different you can create dictionary of columns names with aggregate functions and then set another aggregate functuions for some columns, like for `type3` is used `first` and for `val1` is used `last`:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['type1','type2']), 'max')
d['type3'] = 'first'
d['val1'] = 'last'

df = df.groupby(["type1","type2"], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(d)
print (df)
  type1 type2 type3  val1  val2  val3
0     a     b     q     4     6     7
1     a     c     w     2     5     8
2     b     c     t     2     9     0
```